# selecting, sorting and extracting data from a text file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a text file like this example:

example:

```
fgeyc,MFNG,NM_002405.3,68
fgeyc,DDFR,gfhd,29
fgeyc,GGFHTY,kjg,36
Positive,POS_C(8),gghr,3742
Positive,POS_A(128),gghd,38799
Positive,POS_F(0.125),gght,66
Positive,POS_D(2),gghr,848
fgeyc,POS_B(32),gghy,12953
```

I want to select the rows (`comma separates`) starting with Positive and make a list from the `4th` column. but I want to sort the rows based on the `2nd` column. from `A to F`.

expected output:

```
Pos = [38799, 3742, 848, 66]
```

to do so I made the following code but I do not know how to sort based on the `2nd` column. do you know how to sort them?

```
Pos = []
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f.read().split():
        seg = line.split(",")
        if seg[0] == "Positive":
            value = seg[3]
            Pos.append(value)
```

Comment: Now the question is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort your list of lines

You can use its `key` argument to extract the second column from the row to sort by that

Comment: it is not so simple since the 2nd column is like this:      POS_F(0.125). for me only F is important.

Comment: Well then write a `key` function that extracts `F` from the row to sort by that

Answer (score 0):

```
num = dict()
Pos = []
with open("Untitled.txt", 'r') as opened:
    for row in opened:
        a = ' '.join(row.splitlines()).split(',')
        if a[0] == 'Positive':
            num[a[1][4]] = int(a[3])
for e in sorted(num.keys()):
    Pos.append(num[e])
print(Pos)
```

Comment: This works only considering the first character after '_'. And it produces the desired list of number in Pos. Check if it satisfies all sorts of data in your file.